# How to make one button do 4 different actions based on 4 other buttons in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make it so when the user presses a button for student or faculty, then enters the object details into a couple textfields that open up based on the object button they pressed, and then press the Add button, it will add the the certain object (student or faculty) to the array based on the object button they first pressed in the beginning.

I have handlers for the buttons that all they do is add the corresponding textFields. I just need to make it so when the user presses the student button for instance, the Add button will know to add a student object to the array of objects.

Here's the handlers for the buttons that create textFields

That's all the handlers I have so far. At the bottom is what the GUI looks like. I just need that Add button to know how to add either a parttimestudent, fulltimestudent, etc.  based on which of those buttons at the top is clicked.

```
        ftf.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
            varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars3, vars4);
        });

        ptf.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
            varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars3, vars4);

        });

        pts.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
            varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars1, vars2);
        });

        fts.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
            varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars1, vars2); 
        });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrDHI.png

Edit: Thought of a solution. I will make 4 different add buttons that will appear in the same place on the screen based on the corresponding object button clicked at the top that will add the object to the array.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Create the different handlers:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> addStudentHandler = e -> {
    // code to add student...
};

EventHandler<ActionEvent> addFacultyHandler = e -> {
    // code to add faculty...
};

// etc...
```

Now in your other handlers just choose the appropriate handler for the add button:

```
ftf.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
    varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars3, vars4);
    addButton.setOnAction(addFacultyHandler);
});

fts.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    varsColumn.getChildren().removeAll(vars1, vars2, vars3, vars4);
    varsColumn.getChildren().addAll(vars1, vars2); 
    addButton.setOnAction(addStudentHandler);
});
```